# JQuery $.ajax request returns me "Error 404" even if the resource exists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing an app with TideSDK and I need to send some data to a PHP script that will create a file to store it on the pc. I'm pretty new to AJAX and to send data I do:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(GW2.items);

$.ajax({
    url: "/assets/scripts/save.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { jsonString: jsonString }
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Where GW2.items is a JSON object, "save.php" is my script and jsonString is the variable I want to send.

But, when I try to execute the program it returns me:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:52432/assets/scripts/save.php 404 Not Found
```

And the answer is: *Cannot POST /assets/scripts/save.php*

This is the PHP script:

```
<?php
    $jsonString = $_GET['jsonString'];
    return {};
?>
```

I checked the path and it's correct so why it can't find my file?

Comment: If you hit http://127.0.0.1:52432/assets/scripts/save.php in your browser do you get a 404?

Comment: Are you running your php server locally? Is it running locally on that port? Can you show us sample code for that php endpoint?

Comment: Is the PHP script on the same host that your Javascript came from?

Comment: @mkaatman no, I tried and it ask me to dowload the file. Unfortunatly TideSDK doesn't seems to have a consolo to write in so the only thing I can do is try to inject some sort of feedback in HTML.

Comment: @chapinkapa Yes, it's running locally becouse is managed by the editor (TideSDK). The code il simply 
    $jsonString = $_POST('jsonString');
    return {};

Answer (score 1):

Did you try your path with POST or just GET? It could be exist for GET requests (pasting the url on a browser) but probably not for POST or other HTTP verbs.

You can use REST clients like Postman to be sure, which is also a Chrome extension.

Comment: If I use GET method the response is the PHP script

Comment: Are you making the ajax call from the same domain? There's a security restriction on cross-domain ajax calls. Do you know what CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is? This is a good link to get started if this is your case: http://enable-cors.org/